# Simple react filtering

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I'm trying to use basic filtering with React. All my "tags" have "taglevel".

- I want the first row to show all tag.name with "taglevel" of 1.
- I want the second row to show all tag.name with "taglevel" of 2 or more.

However, I cannot get it to filter on it on "nested" content in my json.

I can get the "titles" in and filtering, but I would like to filter on the nested json content tag.name.

I've put this together in a codepen.

http://codepen.io/yarnball/pen/GqbyWr?editors=1010

Without success, I have now tried the following:

I tried filtering using this using:

```
var LevelFilter = React.createClass({

    render: function(){
        return this.props.tags.filter(tag => tag.taglevel === this.props.targetLevel).map(tag => <a onClick={this.props.onClick}>{tag.name}</a>);
    }
});
```

Then trying to get it in my return here:

```
render: function(){
        var buttonClass = this.state.active ? 'active' : '';
        var titleToSelect = this.selecttitle;
        var getUniqueCategories=[];
        PHOTODATA.forEach(function(el){
            if(getUniqueCategories.indexOf(el.title) === -1 ) getUniqueCategories.push(el.title);
        })

        return (
            <div className="overlay-photogallery">
                <div className="filter-panel"><b>Tags with taglevel 1 only (not title!)</b>
                    {
                        getUniqueCategories.map(function(el,i){
                            var boundClick = titleToSelect.bind(null,el);
                            return <LevelFilter onClick={onClick} targetLevel={1}/>
                        })

                    }
```

Here is a sample of my json:

```
    "title": "Into the Wild",
    "tag": [
        {
            "name": "Movie",
            "taglevel": 1,
            "id": 1
        },
        {
            "name": "Adventure",
            "taglevel": 2,
            "id": 30
        },
        {
            "name": "Book",
            "taglevel": 1,
            "id": 2
        }
    ],
    "info": []
}
```

Comment: To filter an array, you need to use the `filter` method, not `map`.  Also, in your code above, you don't even use the argument `tag` to the function, instead referencing `this.props.name`, which probably doesn't exist.

Comment: what will be the output?? if you indicate on your question it would be helpful to answer.  btw i would sort the json based on the taglevel first and then work with them. To sort an array of objects you can use underscore and lodash or can sort it using for loop.

Answer (score 1):

Could be something like this:

```
var Level1filter = React.createClass({

    render: function(){
        return this.props.tags.filter(tag => tag.taglevel === 1).map(tag => <a onClick={this.props.onClick}>{tag.name}</a>);
    }
});

var Level2filter = React.createClass({

    render: function(){
        return this.props.tags.filter(tag => tag.taglevel === 2).map(tag => <a onClick={this.props.onClick}>{tag.name}</a>);
    }
});
```

now, maybe make something better:

```
var LevelFilter = React.createClass({

    render: function(){
        return this.props.tags.filter(tag => tag.taglevel === this.props.targetLevel).map(tag => <a onClick={this.props.onClick}>{tag.name}</a>);
    }
});

//and use it like this
<LevelFilter onClick={onClick} targetLevel={1}/>
<LevelFilter onClick={onClick} targetLevel={2}/>
```

Arrow Function in case you're not familiar with it: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Comment: Thanks. I've updated my answer to include you option (particularly the "maybe something better" section. It still isn't renering any results. Could you check again? I've updated my codepen- http://codepen.io/yarnball/pen/GqbyWr?editors=0010

Comment: fixed: http://codepen.io/goldbullet/pen/bZPOAK
just onClick had to the correct function name and also undefined check on props.tags

Comment: Thanks! I'm still not seeing the actual "tags" appearing though. My return on 157 is "<LevelFilter onClick={boundClick} targetLevel={1}/>". Should that include something else?

Comment: I haven't gone through all the lines of the code, so I don't know exactly what it's supposed to do, but you would need to pass tags prop to the filter component. see it's using `this.props.tags`. Just so you know, it filters out the tags that taglevel is not the same as this.props.targetLevel and renders the `a` tag using the name and onClick event handler.

Comment: Yes, I think you're right I need to pass/define tags in the component. How is this achieved? Code updated- http://codepen.io/yarnball/pen/GqbyWr?editors=0011. Thanks

Comment: why are you pushing el.title? you want to collect unique tags right? `PHOTODATA.forEach(function(el){
            if(getUniqueCategories.indexOf(el.title) === -1 ) getUniqueCategories.push(el.title);
        })`

Comment: currently `getUniqueCategories` is an array of titles(string). so your el in the map is a string so el.tag doesn't make sense...

Comment: if you need to keep the array of titles, make another array for tags I guess??

Comment: Yes- I want to collect unique tags. I dont think I need to keep the array of titles- I want to return the titles only as the final 'result'. I do no want to use the "titles" as filters. Eg it will only show the titles which apply to the clicked 'tags' above.

Comment: Ok you will need to explain exactly how you want it to work like which component does what...

Comment: I want it to work like so- if no 'tags' are clicked- you'll see all "titles". As you click 'tags', only the 'titles' which contain the 'tags' will appear. I've created a screenshot to explain- http://i.imgur.com/ZkAeMYh.jpg